# How to add Android Device Monitor to Main Toolbar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm following Udacity's Developing Android Apps class, and in their video it shows an icon at the top of Android Studio for a shortcut to Android Device Monitor. My shortcut icon is not there so I had to search to find it.

I'm trying to add it to the toolbar by right clicking and going into "Customize Toolbars and Menus" but I can't find anything. I googled multiple different things and can't seem to find the answer. Not sure if this is a recent change from Android Studio updates.

Is there a way to add this to the top toolbar? Thanks!

Comment: isn't your monitor tab visible on the bottom of your IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fortunately it is :)

open the `customize menu and toolbars` by right clicking the toolbar.

Navigate to *Main toolbar-Android.MainToolBarSdkGroup* and then click `Add after...` (in fact you can choose whatever position you like most).

Then simply choose *All actions-Main menu-Tools-Android-Android device monitor*

Profit – robot is there :)

Comment: I am following this process to add PugIns to the main menu. It works OK, but if I restart Android Studio the new menu item is not displayed. It does, however, show up in the customize menu and toolbars list